# Carousel slider loads first but images take time to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using carousel slider in my website using bootstrap.

**Problem:**

When i open my webpage the slider in header section loads first but first image take time to load on the slider. I want to solve my problem.

**What i want :**

I want that if slider loads then images must be load at the same time otherwise if images taking time to load then slider should be load when images are ready to load on the webpage.

Kindly suggest me what i should do.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code or is possible create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: jsfiddle.net/MBu5Z   this link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MBu5Z/

Answer (score 0):

If you slider contains more than 10 images and if images are of big size, then follow these steps,

1. Apply src to only first 3 images of slider. For rest images, apply image url to new attribute 'delayedsrc'. delayedsrc attribute contains your image url. Also apply class 'defered_loading' to these images.

then add this js code,

```
$('.defered_loading').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('delayedsrc'));
            }).promise().done(function() {
                // intialize your slider here
            });
```